# What's the intuition behind and some illustrative applications of probability kernels?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, intuition

Given measure spaces $(X, \mathcal{X})$ and $(Y, \mathcal{Y})$ we define measure kernel $\pi : \mathcal{X} \times Y \to [0,\infty]$ such that $\pi(\cdot|y)$ is a measure on $\mathcal{X}$ for every $y \in Y$ and $\pi(A|\cdot)$ is $\mathcal{Y}$-measurable for every $A \in \mathcal{X}$. Probability kernel is then a measure kernel with $\pi(X|y) = 1$ for every $y \in Y$.

Now, this definition is a little abstruse, so I'd like to gain some intuition about it. I can see similarities with usual kernels of operators (because measure is a generalization of a function, at least naively). Also, I can think of the kernel as a collection of measures indexed by $y \in Y$. But I am not sure which of these two views (or if any) gives much insight into why this concept is natural and useful.

> 1. What is the intuition behind the probability kernels?
> 2. What are some applications that show their usefulness?

---

To be more precise about what I am after. There is a definition of group action $\rho$ of group $G$ on set $M$ as $\rho : G \times M \to M$ satisfying certain axioms. But this doesn't really give me any insight. If however someone told me that group action is actually nothing else than homomorphism $\rho : G \to {\rm Aut}(M)$ then I can immediately see the usefulness (given that I know enough group theory, of course). Is there something similar behind probability kernels too?

Comment: @Theo: sounds fine to me. If you'd also provide some usual applications and packaged that into an answer, I couldn't ask for more :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28033/measure-theory-question-about-densities/28110#28110 with some obvious changes of notation.

Comment: @Didier: very illuminating, thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a quote (page 20) from  one of my favorite books on probability, *Foundations of Modern Probability (2nd edition)* by Olav Kallenberg.

> "Kernels play an important role in probability, where they may appear in the guises of random measures, conditional distributions, Markov transition functions, and potentials."

In my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9161/concept-of-random-walk/9173#9173), I try to explain how kernels are used to build a **stochastic process**, that is, to describe a random system that evolves in time. You begin with an initial distribution for $X(0)$, then a conditional distribution that tells you how $X(1)$ will behave given $X(0)$, then a conditional distribution that tells you how $X(2)$ will behave given the pair $X(0),X(1)$, etc.

This is only one application of the idea, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is actually very close to what I need to learn about the kernels for, namely specifications and Gibbs measures.

Comment: @Marek I'm glad it helps.