# Difference between conditional probability and "kernel"

Tags: probability

Is there a difference between the two? Can a "kernel" be seen as the distribution of a random "object" given a realization of another variable?

Comment: Maybe my answer here helps? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33430/whats-the-intuition-behind-and-some-illustrative-applications-of-probability-ke/33472#33472

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Thank you. I guess I can think of a transition kernel as some kind of conditional probability to make things simpler for me, because they both describe transitioning how a random object transitions.

Answer (score 1):

Like much of statistics, this is a parameter versus estimator issue.
Consider the probability distribution of a random variable $X$ as a
parameter itself (which, under non-parametric statistics is reasonable). Thus,
this parameter is the function $P_X(x).$ THe kernel of this probability is the
estimator of the distribution, $\hat{P_X}(x)$. Kernel density estimation is
the non-parametric procedure used to find a realization of this estimator.